# How to delete recent items from the the Xcode icon on the Dock?

Tags: xcode, project, contextmenu, dock, recent-file-list

I deleted some test projects from the Finder but I still see them on the Xcode icon contextual menu on the Dock. How should I remove them from this menu?

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is a question how to interpret what the Finder shows. If you deleted the projects, they are gone. The proof is that if you click on any of them on that menu you will get an error.

Comment: yeah sorry about it but how can I remove them?

Comment: I improved your question. Please see the changes, so that you can ask a better, clearer question next time. Please see my reply below. If that solves the problem, you should upvote it or at least you should accept it. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to the menu `File` -> `Open Recent`
3. Click on `Clear Menu`

Your recent items should be gone after that either on this menu and on the contextual menu on the Xcode icon on the Dock.